# How do I insert UCS-2 data with PHP PDO into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, pdo

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html) clearly states " ucs2 cannot be used as a client character set, which means that it does not work for SET NAMES or SET CHARACTER SET". So how can I insert, for example, the codepoint U+2193? I am using PHP 5.3 + PDO.

Comment: You can probably get away with using UTF-16. Most of the code points are the same.

Comment: What about using UTF-8 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Unicode for communicating with a MySQL server, your only option is to use UTF-8.

If you're working with UCS-2 or UTF-16 strings in PHP now, you'll have to convert them to UTF-8 before trying to store them. Also note that MySQL will give you back UTF-8 if that's what you set your client character set to, so you'll need to convert query results as well if you're committed to working with UCS-2 on the PHP side. (If you're in a position to make bigger changes, you'd likely be better off simply using UTF-8 everywhere than doing all this extra conversion.)

As for storing the codepoint U+2193, no worries: UTF-8 can represent every Unicode codepoint (in this specific case, it'd be `0xE2 0x86 0x93`).

Technically, this is fudging a little, since MySQL's `utf8` and `ucs2` character sets only cover a subset of Unicode called the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). The world of Unicode charsets is [expanded in MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html) to move beyond the BMP, but you still can't use `ucs2`, the new `utf16` or `utf32` charsets as client charsets, leaving you still stuck with  UTF-8.

Comment: Well, OK, but why the heck does MySQL have a ucs2 character set (and collations) if you cant use them??

Comment: You can store data in those encodings, if you have a plausible reason to (maybe large chunks of CJK?). You just can't have the database server and the client talk to each other in them. It shouldn't be important what encoding is used for the client-server link as long as both sides agree on it and it covers all characters the application wants (which a UTF always will).

Comment: UTF-16 is somewhat of a second-class citizen in much of the \*ix world, including for MySQL and indeed PHP. Are you *sure* you really have UTF-16/UCS-2 data in PHP? It offers few tools for dealing usefully for byte strings in this encoding. You are more likely to be using the much more sensible encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, `CREATE TABLE test (encoding varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ucs2);` and then `INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, CHAR(0x2193));`. If I then run a `SELECT * FROM test` I see a down arrow.

Comment: Just note that unless you set `character_set_results` to binary or ucs2, MySQL will be automatically converting your results to another encoding, even though they're stored as UCS-2.